# Has A relationship where the owned can know about owner

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have two classes `Device` and `DeviceMemory`, `Device` has a field `memory` of type `DeviceMemory` so that when `Device` is destroyed the `DeviceMemory` gets freed.

```
class DeviceMemory {
    void func();
}

class Device {
    VkPhysicalDevice phys_dev;
    VkDevice logi_dev;

    DeviceMemory memory;
}
```

How can I make `func` be able to access `phys_dev` and `logi_dev` from the owning device ?

Comment: If they are this tightly coupled, should they really be separate objects?

Comment: DeviceMemory should have a reference for  Device (passed in DeviceMemory  constructor for example), or phys_dev/logi_dev should be passed as parameters to func

Comment: This sounds like a bad design.  What is this `func` really, and why does the memory need to know which device owns it?

Comment: @Matt because having every single function inside `DeviceMemory` have `VkPhysicalDevice phys_dev` as an argument feels tedious

Comment: @MacelaruTiberiu Your question is too vague to make a concise decision.

Comment: One of the rules of OO design is that an object must not collaborate with the peers of its peers--it must collaborate only with its immediate peers. In your case, if you want `DeviceMemory.func()` to do something to `phys_dev` and `logi_dev`, delegate that to a function of `Device`.